"an error has occured. see the log file."
I have a problem with the STM32Cube IDE app. I don't know why I can't get into it. I try to open with another way, but i still don't find my solution. Can anyone help me? I am still very new to this world.
I just want to try to open it because I have to finish my college work


Please add the entire log message starting with !SESSION and including the entire stack trace as text to your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <). The ClassNotFoundException sound like that your installation is broken. If you updated an older version of STM32CubeIDE to 1.15.1 or installed additional plugins, you might try a fresh installation.
